# How to upload image to aws pre signed url as multipart data using Alamofire 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, alamofire

I am trying to upload an image to the pre-signed AWS URL. I tried with Alamofire 5 upload method which accepts multipartData. I am getting a 403 error with Alamofire 5 multipart upload.

When I try with URLSession it is working properly.

```
/// Working code

        var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.httpBody = image
        request.setValue("image/jpeg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let tasksession: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (response, urlResp, error) in
            if let data: Data = response {
                do {
                    let json: [String: Any]? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                    debugPrint("json \(json)")
                }
                catch {
                    debugPrint("error \(error)")
                }
            }



            print(response ?? "response nil")
            print(error ?? "response nil")
        })
        tasksession.resume()
```

Same when I try with AF 5 it is not working

// Not working code.

```
 AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiPart) in

            multiPart.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }, to: url, method: .put, headers: ["Content-Type": "image/jpeg"],
                                                  ])
        .uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
                    //Current upload progress of the file
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })
                .responseJSON(completionHandler: { data in
                    let json: [String: Any]? = data as? [String: Any]
                    debugPrint("upload complete json \(data)")
            })
```

Could someone tell why it is not working with multipart upload with Alamofire 5, multipart upload is working in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire Version 4.9.1

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            //Any Post Params if you have.
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to:uploadUrlStr) //uploadUrlStr: upload url in your case
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Uploading")
                    print(CGFloat(progress.fractionCompleted * 100))
                })
                
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print("Upload Finished")
                    guard let resultValue = response.result.value else {
                        NSLog("Result value in response is nil")
                        return
                    }

                }
                
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

This is working for me.

Comment: is it for AWS pre-signed url?

Comment: Yes, I am using this code for upload image to amazon S3 bucket

Comment: Did not work still I am getting 403 error did you specify how is your code different from mine and one more thing I have observed is with multipart in request body is going null i think that is the main reason for failure.

Comment: Some syntax changes in Almofire...and I can see you are missing one closing bracket in headers: ["Content-Type": "image/jpeg", ...is it in the question only or the same is in your code.

Comment: That I have copy-pasted wrongly other than this anything else because you are saying it is working without headers in your case?

Comment: Yes for me it is working without method and header. I am using the same in couple of apps.

Comment: Sorry I just checked I am using AF 4.9.1 ... but I am updaing it to 5 to check if that will work on AF5 or not.

Comment: Hello, What's in your parameters object in you for loop?

Comment: @jlstr if you want to send any post params while uploading then you can do it as mentioned. parameters is a simple dictionay. comment if you need more info on this..Happy to help!